# Xamarin android cannot find symbol extends android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Not able compile xamarin.android project with xamarin.forms(2.3.1.114).

Getting error as follows :

> FrameRenderer.java(35,35): Error:  error: cannot find symbol extends
>   android.support.v7.widget.CardView symbol:   class CardView location:
>   package android.support.v7.widget(test2) javac
>
> FrameRenderer.java(7,7): Error:  error: cannot find symbol if
>   (getClass () == FrameRenderer.class) symbol:   method getClass()
>   location: class FrameRenderer (test2) javac
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 6.1.2.21 (Xamarin Indie) Android SDK:
>   /Users/krishnankm/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
>     Supported Android versions:
>         4.0.3  (API level 15)
>         4.1    (API level 16)
>         4.2    (API level 17)
>         4.3    (API level 18)
>         4.4    (API level 19)
>         4.4.87 (API level 20)
>         5.0    (API level 21)
>         5.1    (API level 22)
>         6.0    (API level 23)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 25.1.7 SDK Platform Tools Version: 24.0.1 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 24.0.1
>
> Java SDK: /usr java version "1.8.0_31" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   (build 1.8.0_31-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Might be due to corrupted zip files. Delete the Xamarin zip files (just cardview or all) in  the `{Windows root directory}\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Xamarin`. On the next build everything will be re downloaded (build would take sometime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be due to corrupted zip files.

Delete the Xamarin zip files (just cardview or all) in the

> {Windows root directory}\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Xamarin

On the next build everything will be re downloaded (build would take sometime).

Answer (score 6):

For me i just needed to do `clean solution` then `build solution` and just run it on the device / emulator